# Iterating over multidimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of dimension (a,b,c). And I want to slice it to over c'th dimension. For eg: A numpy array of shape (2,3,4), I want to iterate over 4 arrays of dimension (2,3).

So far I have been doing

```
for i in range(c):
    arr = A[::,i]
```

But this doesn't compute the right thing. How can I compute this?

Comment: `range(A.shape[-1])`

Comment: I have all the dimensions a,b,c. I want to slice the numpy array to get four 2*3 arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma. Your code should look like:

```
for i in range(c):
    arr = A[:,:,i]
```

BTW the code above is computing the right thing, but you are writing a statement that doesn't solve your problem :)

Comment: Can you provide some links to understand these kind of syntax

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it also take a comma between the colons? Like so : 
arr = A[:, :, i]